# Avoiding an incomplete pattern match

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching, refactoring

Consider the following code:

```
data A
data B

f :: A -> B
f = undefined

data T = TA A | TB B
data ListT = ListTA [A] | ListTB [B]

g :: [T] -> ListT
g l = 
  let
    f' :: T -> B
    f' (TA x) = f x
    f' (TB x) = x
    isA :: T -> Bool
    isA TA{} = True
    isA TB{} = False
  in
    case (all isA l) of
      True -> ListTA (map (\(TA x) -> x) l)
      False -> ListTB (map f' l)

main = pure ()
```

The idea behind this is I've got a list of either `A`s or `B`s mixed together. I can convert `A -> B` but not the other way around. Based on this list, I want to make either a list of `A`s or list of `B`s, the former if all my original list elements are `A`s, the latter if at least one is a `B`.

The above code compiles (and I'm guessing will work) but the incomplete pattern match in the `map (\(TA x) -> x) l` makes me just a little uncomfortable. Is such an incomplete match just a necessity of what I'm doing here? Also, am I reinventing the wheel, is there something that generalises what I'm doing here?

Comment: What should the code do if the list is a mixture of As and Bs?

Comment: What if you extract `\(TA x) -> x` into a function and complete that function's pattern match with an error/assert of some sorts? While more verbose, that would definitely help you against future additions to the constructor of T, which may go unnoticed for some time otherwise.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid convert all the As to Bs using 'f'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help from the other answers, I'm going to answer my own question for the benefit of future viewers. I believe the most suscinct function for `g` is as follows (and noticed I've generalised to `Traversable` instead of just lists).

```
data ListT t = ListTA (t A) | ListTB (t B)

g :: (Traversable t) => t T -> ListT t
g l = 
  let
    f2B :: T -> B
    f2B (TA x) = f x
    f2B (TB x) = x
    f2A :: T -> Maybe A
    f2A (TA x) = Just x
    f2A (TB x) = Nothing
  in
    maybe (ListTB (fmap f2B l)) ListTA (traverse f2A l)

main = pure ()
```

On lists, this should only take space proportional to the number of leading `A`s, which is minimal I believe.

Comment: `toA (TA a) = Just a ; toA _ = Nothing ; g xs = fromJust $ (fmap ListTA . traverse toA) xs <|> (Just . ListTB . map f') xs`. though `fromJust` is partial, the presence of `Just` in the alternative reveals totality of the whole.  pointfree, it's `g = fromJust . ((<|>) . fmap ListTA . traverse toA <*> Just . ListTB . map f')`. this is the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946040/849891), repackaged.

Comment: or it could be (a bit more readable) `fromJust . uncurry (<|>) . (fmap ListTA . traverse toA &&& Just . ListTB . map f')`, whatever your preference in such things.

Comment: but your use of `maybe` is better. Should've read your answer first. (just, maybe use `traverse` and not `mapM`).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is something like

```
tryA :: [T] -> Maybe [A]
tryA [] = []
tryA (t:ts) =
  case t of
    TA x -> do xs <- tryA ts; return (x:xs)
    TB _ -> Nothing
```

If `tryA` returns nothing, then do `map f' l` as before.

This way you're doing the `all isA l` and the `map` in a single pass, and it avoids an incomplete pattern.

Comment: You're right. Author just learned about _bool blindness_. Instead of relying on `Bool` you should better use some evidence. This is common pattern in functional programming. Read this blog post: https://cs-syd.eu/posts/2016-07-24-overcoming-boolean-blindness-evidence.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd structure it like this: build *two* lists - one full of `A`s and one full of `B`s - with the effect that building the list of `A`s could fail. One can build a `Monoid` which implements this logic and [`foldMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) into it.

Since one could fail to build a list of `A`s, we'll need to build this  `Monoid` on top of `Maybe`. The behaviour we want comes from `Maybe`'s `Applicative` instance: if either of `mappend`'s arguments is `Nothing` then the whole thing fails, otherwise we want to use `mappend` to combine the two results. This is a general recipe for combining an `Applicative` and a `Monoid`. Concretely:

```
newtype WrappedApplicative f a = Wrap { unWrap :: f a }

instance (Applicative f, Monoid m) => Monoid (WrappedApplicative f m) where
    mempty = pure mempty
    Wrap x `mappend` Wrap y = Wrap $ liftA2 mappend x y
```

I don't know if this `newtype` is somewhere in `base`. It seems like the sort of thing that would be there but I couldn't find it.

Without further ado, here's the `Monoid` we'll be `foldMap`ping into:

```
type Result = ([B], WrappedApplicative Maybe [A])
```

I'm borrowing [`(a, b)`'s `Monoid` instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-278), which delegates in parallel to `a` and `b`'s `Monoid` instances.

```
getAsOrToBs :: [Either A B] -> Either [A] [B]
getAsOrToBs = fromResult . foldMap toResult
    where toResult (Left a) = ([aToB a], Wrap (Just [a]))
          toResult (Right b) = ([b], Wrap Nothing)
          fromResult (_, Wrap (Just as)) = Left as
          fromResult (bs, Wrap Nothing) = Right bs
```

Alternatively, with `foldr`:

```
getAsOrToBs :: [Either A B] -> Either [A] [B]
getAsOrToBs = fromResult . foldr f ([], Just [])
    where f (Left a) (bs, mas) = (aToB a : bs, fmap (a:) mas)
          f (Right b) (bs, _) = (b:bs, Nothing)
          fromResult (_, Just as) = Left as
          fromResult (bs, Nothing) = Right bs
```

Look, ma, no partial functions!

Comment: what would you say about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944389/avoiding-an-incomplete-pattern-match/44946040#comment76947174_44950978) re "presence of `Just` in alternative ..." validates the use of `fromJust` overall? could it redeem that use of `from Just` in your opinion? at least it's short and only uses standard `Maybe` instances. (and skimming through your post without reading it closely, since Alternative is  Applicative's Monoid, isn't your post recreating that functionality? ... just a superficial impression).

Comment: @WillNess Yes and no, I guess. Any time you use a partial function you're asserting something you believe to be true about your code. You could be wrong, in which case your assertion will fail and crash the program. Clearly `x <|> Just y` will always return a `Just`, so `fromJust` is justified in some sense, but on the other hand the code might change at some point in the future and the use of `fromJust` prevents the type system from giving you feedback. Kinda like how you _can_ write correct code with pointers or mutability but it's safer not to :)

Comment: yeah, thanks; in the mean time I realized `maybe` is better there - for the reasons you describe: no partial functions, just two plain alternatives.